# root cron not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, ubuntu-10.04

I have a root user cron setup to run every one hour. I manually ran the rake task and it ran successfully as root user. But when i added this rake task as a cron, it doesn't work, I checked the /var/log/syslog and it seems to have the run the cron and also I redirected the stdout and stderr and examined the file, but the file seems to be empty. My guess is that there is an issue with running the cron as a root user. Has anyone face this problem before.?

**Quick Update**

In the stdout/stderr logs I'm getting a missing gems, I'm using RVM and I have installed my gems both globally and the gemset which I'm currently using.

Comment: I'm voting to move this to serverfault.com as that seems like a much better place for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like maybe rake can't be found in the default cron environment. Try first changing to the appropriate directory, and then this below, which will try to locate rake and then run it:

```
0 */1 * * * cd /app/directory; /usr/bin/env rake <task>
```

Also try adding setting a `PATH` that includes the path to rvm binaries:

```
PATH=/usr/local/rvm/bin;/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

(Substitute `/usr/local/rvm/bin` with the path to rvm on your system)

Comment: Ya I did this, but still it didn't work, Iam using rvm and in the stdout/stderr log file it says, missing gems, though I have installed my gems both as global and the current gemset I use.

Comment: @Prozac, try setting a `PATH` environment variable that includes the path to rvm binaries. See my update.